# Fixing Curling Vinyl Flooring

Tags: bathroom, flooring

I have vinyl flooring in the bathroom that has started to curl up a bit at the edge. It was suggested to me that I use contact cement to fix it. The problem is that there is not enough curl to allow space for me to get at the sub floor or the underside of the vinyl flooring in order to apply the cement. Do I need to rip up more of the floor to expose enough surface area? If so, how can I do that in a controlled manner?

Comment: Can you see the floor underneath?  Is it damp, is there mildew, any rot?  The curling floor may be a sign of larger problems.

Comment: That's a good point and one that had occurred to me. I don't see anything right now, but there's not much room to see until I peel back more of the floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to install quarter round next to the baseboards. If the edge has barely started curling up, this would hold it down.

Otherwise, yes you will have to peel the vinyl back to apply adhesive to it. One method to make the floor a bit more pliable is to use a hairdryer to heat it up. Just make sure you don't overheat it too much.

Before applying the new adhesive, you may have to scrape off some of the old adhesive, and clean off any resulting debris.

Here's a good article with more details: [Link](http://www.ehow.com/how_5868172_fix-curled-vinyl-flooring.html)

Comment: I should probably mention that the curl is where the floor meets the bathtub. Is quarter round appropriate in that location?

Comment: Oh, probably not then. :) Kindly disregard that bit.